# prediction with LSTM in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm stuck with a problem with my LSTM. What I want to do is the following:

I have a dataset in the form:

```
0.04,-9.77,0.71,1,0,0,0
...
...
```

The first three parameters are data collected by an accelerometer: X acceleration, Y acceleration, Z acceleration

The last four columns are the labels:

```
[1,0,0,0] [0,1,0,0] [0,0,1,0] [0,0,0,1] [0,0,0,0]
```

where each one represents a different class.

My network is declared as follows:

```
 class Config:
        def __init__(self):
            """network parameters"""
            self.batch_size = 16
            self.input_size = 3
            self.seq_max_len = 20
            self.rnn_size = 50
            self.keep_prob = 1
            self.mlp_hidden_size = 100
            self.mlp_projection_activation = tf.nn.tanh
            self.num_classes = 4
            self.learning_rate = 0.001
            self.epochs = 10
    
    
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(config.seq_max_len, config.input_size)),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=config.rnn_size, return_sequences=True, return_state=False),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=config.mlp_hidden_size, activation=config.mlp_projection_activation),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=config.num_classes, activation='softmax'),
    ])
    
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=config.batch_size, epochs=config.epochs)
```

Now, the problem is that this is not working as i would. When i try to predict, let's say using an array:

```
arr = np.array([(-0.12,-9.85,0.82),(-1.33,-10,1.61),(-1.57,-10.04,0.9),(0.08,-9.14,0.51),(3.77,-8.36,-0.55),(6.71,-8.43,-1.69),
(9.22,-8.28,-2.63),(10.75,-7.65,-2.98),(9.26,-7.61,-2.35),(6.16,-7.85,-1.77),(2.35,-8.51,-0.78),(-1.10,-8.87,0.71),(-3.61,-9.14,2.31),
                (-5.49,-9.65,3.69),
                (-5.33,-9.49,3.14),
                (-4.24,-9.26,3.30),
                (-2.43,-9.06,2.24),
                (-0.39,-8.87,1.29),
                (3.61,-8.55,-1.22),
                (7.10,-8.28,-1.57)])
```

Composed by 20 triplette of 3d vectors (accelerations) what i obtain is

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(arr)
[[0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0]]
```

which is a vector that represents a prediction for each triplette in the arr vector. What i want, is to have ONLY ONE prediction, after the 20 triplette. This is because my data represent a time series and what i am interested in, is to know if the network is able to classify data after a certain amount of acceleration vectors (20 in this case).

Can help me please?

EDIT

full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

def get_dataset(filename, config):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, skiprows=1)
    x = df[[0, 1, 2]].values
    y = df[[3, 4, 5, 6]].values
    dataset_x, dataset_y = [],[]

    for i in range(x.shape[0]//config.seq_max_len):
        sequence_x, sequence_y = [],[]
        for j in range(config.seq_max_len):
            sequence_x.append(x[i*config.seq_max_len + j])
            sequence_y.append(y[i*config.seq_max_len + j])
        dataset_x.append(sequence_x)
        dataset_y.append(sequence_y)

    return np.array(dataset_x), np.array(dataset_y)


class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        """definizione dei parametri della rete"""
        self.batch_size = 16
        self.input_size = 3
        self.seq_max_len = 20
        self.rnn_size = 50
        self.keep_prob = 1
        self.mlp_hidden_size = 100
        self.mlp_projection_activation = tf.nn.tanh
        self.num_classes = 4
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.epochs = 10

config = Config()

x_train, y_train = get_dataset('data_new.csv', config)

arr = np.array([(-0.12,-9.85,0.82),(-1.33,-10,1.61),(-1.57,-10.04,0.9),(0.08,-9.14,0.51),(3.77,-8.36,-0.55),(6.71,-8.43,-1.69),
(9.22,-8.28,-2.63),(10.75,-7.65,-2.98),(9.26,-7.61,-2.35),(6.16,-7.85,-1.77),(2.35,-8.51,-0.78),(-1.10,-8.87,0.71),(-3.61,-9.14,2.31),
                (-5.49,-9.65,3.69),
                (-5.33,-9.49,3.14),
                (-4.24,-9.26,3.30),
                (-2.43,-9.06,2.24),
                (-0.39,-8.87,1.29),
                (3.61,-8.55,-1.22),
                (7.10,-8.28,-1.57)])
arr2 = np.reshape(arr,(1,20,3))
print(arr2.shape)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(config.seq_max_len, config.input_size)),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=config.rnn_size, return_sequences=True, return_state=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=config.mlp_hidden_size, activation=config.mlp_projection_activation),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=config.num_classes, activation='softmax'),
])


loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=config.batch_size, epochs=config.epochs)
predictions = model.predict(arr2)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
print("PREDIZIONI---------")
print(predictions.shape)
print(predictions)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues. One is if you set

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=.., return_sequences=True, return_state=False)
```

You would get as follows if you print `model. summary()` in the final layer of your model. And that probably not what you want in your final layer.

```
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 20, 4)             404       
=================================================================
```

So, you should use `return_sequence = False` to get the final layer output shape as follows:

```
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
```

Second, you set in your loss function that

```
 ....CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

but you set `activation='softma'` in the final layer to get the probabilities instead of logits.

```
....Dense(units=config.num_classes, activation='softmax')
```

So, based on this set the parameter as follows:

```
....LSTM(units=.., return_sequences=False, return_state=False)
...
....CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False) # compute probabilities 
...
y_pred = model.predict(arr)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
```

Comment: if i try with your suggestion i obtain: ValueError: Shapes (None, 20, 4) and (None, 4) are incompatible

Comment: what's the last layer output shape of your model? and what's the shape of your label? Both must be shape size, e..g model output `(None, 4)` and label shape `(None, 4)`.

Comment: as you can see my last layer is: tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=config.num_classes, activation='softmax')   i can not understand where i am mistaking and what

Comment: Can you share reproducible code with dummy data (in colab)?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_G_lgElL3kOeK_k7vfVVlhfmE8sO1aC/view?usp=sharing here the dataset

Comment: and i've added the full code in the main question

Comment: I didn't get your google drive file, it's still in private mode.

Comment: try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_G_lgElL3kOeK_k7vfVVlhfmE8sO1aC/view?usp=sharing